# How much bytes has been sent over a specific socket?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm building a client in `C#` that comunicates with a server in `Python`. The client sends files to the server using the `Socket.send()` method, and uses threads to be able to send multiple files asynchronously using a `BackgroundWorker`:

```
private void initializeSenderDaemon()
{
    senderDaemon = new BackgroundWorker 
    { 
        WorkerReportsProgress = true,
    };
    senderDaemon.DoWork += sendFile; 
}
```

When some condition is met, the `RunWorkerAsync()` method is called and a file is sent

Both client and the server acknowledge on the size of the file before begin the transfer

I want to be able to track how much of the file has been sent from client side

I've though about something like this **CONCEPTUAL CODE, I KNOW THAT IT DOESN'T WORK**

```
byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(path); // original file
byte[] chunk = null; // auxiliar variable, declared outside of the loop for simplicity sake
int chunkSize = fileContents.Length / 100; //  we will asume that the file length is a multiplier of 100 for simplicity sake

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
    Array.Copy(fileContents, i * chunkSize, chunk, i * chunkSize, chunkSize);
    // Copy(Array sourceArray, int sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, int destinationIndex, int length); 
    s.Send(chunk);
    reportProgress(i);
}

reportProgress(100);
```

There are obvious issues with that code, but I wrote it just to explain what I want to do

¿How can I track how many bytes has been already sent to the server for one specific file?
¿There is any way to do it without relying on workarounds?
¿Should I use other method from the socket class?

Thanks!

Comment: `fileContents.Length / 100` cannot grantee that whole file will be sent !

Comment: what is the file size is 101 bytes ? you will end up sending only 100 bytes!

Comment: @AppDeveloper, I knew about that, read my comments. The second portion of the code is only conceptual

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604324/progress-bar-for-file-transfer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
int bSent = 0;
int fileBytesRead;

FileStream fileStream = File.Open(tmpFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
while ((fileBytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    socket.Send(buffer, 0, fileBytesRead);
    bSent += fileBytesRead;

    arg.Progress = (int) (bSent*100/totalBytes);
    arg.Speed = (bSent/sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    OnProgress(arg);
}
```

this answer is not a perfect answer, its just a extract from my work, but will give you a rough idea on better way to send the file using the socket!

Comment: Good answer, but what is the `sw` in the line
`arg.Speed = (bSent/sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);`?

Comment: @warcraker - its the speed at which file is being transferred, in bytes/second.

Comment: Ah ok, now I see that it's a `StopWatch`